# I need more information about sound.extract()

Tags: actionscript-3, audio

I need to do some sound mix work. I have found the example on the Adobe help:

```
var sourceSnd:Sound = new Sound();
var outputSnd:Sound = new Sound();
var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("test.mp3");

sourceSnd.load(urlReq);
sourceSnd.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded);

function loaded(event:Event):void
{
    outputSnd.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, processSound);
    outputSnd.play();
}

function processSound(event:SampleDataEvent):void
{
    var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    sourceSnd.extract(bytes, 4096);
    event.data.writeBytes(upOctave(bytes));
}

function upOctave(bytes:ByteArray):ByteArray
{
    var returnBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    bytes.position = 0;
    while(bytes.bytesAvailable > 0)
    {
        returnBytes.writeFloat(bytes.readFloat());
        returnBytes.writeFloat(bytes.readFloat());
        if (bytes.bytesAvailable > 0)
        {
            bytes.position += 8;
        }
    }
    return returnBytes;
}
```

It said:

```
target:ByteArray — A ByteArray object in which the extracted sound samples are placed.

length:Number — The number of sound samples to extract. A sample contains both the left and right channels — that is, two 32-bit floating-point values.
```

I suggest

```
    returnBytes.writeFloat(bytes.readFloat());
    returnBytes.writeFloat(bytes.readFloat());
```

Must write the leftchannel value and rightchannel value.

```
bytes.position += 8
```

Decrease the sample so the sound play faster. I have tried to modify the value to 4. The speed slow down, to 2, and I only got noise, why? Other values, like 16 or higher, no sound output. Why? How to make various sound effect by only one float value?

I need more information to understand my work, please help.

**update**: i change the upOctave() function a little bit, the speed can be adjust now.

```
        function upOctave(bytes:ByteArray):ByteArray
        {
            var returnBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            bytes.position = 0;
            var position:int = 0;
            var speed:Number = 0.75;
            while(bytes.bytesAvailable > 0)
            {
                if (bytes.bytesAvailable > 0)
                {
                    bytes.position = int(speed*position)*8;
                }
                position++;
                if(bytes.bytesAvailable>0){
                    returnBytes.writeFloat(bytes.readFloat());
                    returnBytes.writeFloat(bytes.readFloat());
                }
            }
            return returnBytes;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, `bytes.position += 8;` not means playrate.

4 bytes per float and two channels. Move, as shown in the image below.

8 byteArray is 1 set. In other words Sampling.

```
 4byte  4byte
[  L  ][  R  ] [  L  ][  R  ] [  L  ][  R  ] [  L  ][  R  ] ...

       1              2              3              4
```

L,R 32 float. Continuous data between -1 and 1. like Sin function.

Create a waveform, you can control the sound. Straight wave, sawtooth wave, triangular wave, sine wave, noise wave... Eventually the sound depends on the waveform.

If you want adjust playrate read a this article: http://www.kelvinluck.com/2008/11/first-steps-with-flash-10-audio-programming/

Comment: thanks,since i understood the structure , i can change the speed now,please see the code above^^.can you tell more info about the nouns you mentioned about the waveform?