# Actionscript 3 - How can I loop the audio using this mp3 speed / pitch changer?

Tags: loops, actionscript-3, audio, pitch

I am using a modified version of an Adobe script, that increases the speed of an MP3 audio file. The modified version  (provided by user2003548) allows you to increase or decrease the speed in a more variable way. Thanks to that user !!! (basically he modified the upOctave function).

Their original post is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14785842/i-need-more-information-about-sound-extract), but I'll repost the modified code here...

```
var sourceSnd:Sound = new Sound();
var outputSnd:Sound = new Sound();
var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest("test.mp3");

sourceSnd.load(urlReq);
sourceSnd.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded);

function loaded(event:Event):void
{
    outputSnd.addEventListener(SampleDataEvent.SAMPLE_DATA, processSound);
    outputSnd.play();
}

function processSound(event:SampleDataEvent):void
{
    var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    sourceSnd.extract(bytes, 4096);
    event.data.writeBytes(upOctave(bytes));
}

function upOctave(bytes:ByteArray):ByteArray
    {
        var returnBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        bytes.position = 0;
        var position:int = 0;
        var speed:Number = 0.75;
        while(bytes.bytesAvailable > 0)
        {
            if (bytes.bytesAvailable > 0)
            {
                bytes.position = int(speed*position)*8;
            }
            position++;
            if(bytes.bytesAvailable>0){
                returnBytes.writeFloat(bytes.readFloat());
                returnBytes.writeFloat(bytes.readFloat());
            }
        }
        return returnBytes;
    }
```

So you basically put an mp3 file (named test.mp3) in the same folder as this script and it'll play the audio at a different speed, depending on the value of the variable 'speed'.

In my version I substituted the value of speed to the value of a slider and that allowed me to adjust the speed dynamically, so it does exactly what I need.

What I'm looking to do, is create an engine sound that I can control the speed / pitch of. So I just want the audio to loop (as seamlessly as possible) and not play just once.

I've tried outputSnd.play(0,9999) but that didn't work. I must admit I don't fully understand what's happening in the script, other than it's very clever. I think the sound that's being played is sort of being streamed from bytes returned from the upOctave function and the looping probably has to happen in there somewhere. But I don't seem to be able to make this audio loop. If there's anyone out there that can help that would be amazing :-)

Many Thanks
Gaz

Comment: Don't know if it would work but here's an idea. Check in `processSound` if you've reached the end of the `sourceSnd`, when you hit the end, call `souceSound.load(urlReq)` again. Every time you call `extract` the position of the source bytearray gets moved forward. You could use that to determine if that sound has finished by keeping track how many bytes you have processed and comparing with `bytesTotal`.

Comment: @DodgerThud Will lag. It will be simpler and faster to listen to SOUND_COMPLETE event to start it again.

Comment: @Organis Ah, I think you're right. Either way OP, you should probably look out how much bytes you're writing to your `outputSound`, otherwise the size will just accumulate until you hit your memory limit.

Comment: Thanks Both. I tried a SOUND_COMPLETE listener temporarily to trigger a trace("finished"); However it never seemed to identify when the sound was complete as nothing appeared. As I can vary the speed of the audio dynamically, I don't think the sound is working in the same way as a preloaded sound file. It seems to be being processed externally and fed back to the sound channel. I won't pretend I understand what I'm talking about, because I don't. :-)  If I enter sourceSND.play(0,9999) it loops, if I enter outputSND.play(0,9999), it doesn't, so it seems to be behaving differently.